# css change div width if no

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive design that includes a 'sidebar' containing multiple divs, the exact number of which will vary - but for the purpose of this question lets say 3 or 4.

When viewed on a wide/full/desktop display, each of the divs in the sidebar will stack on top of one another vertically.

With an @media max-width declaration, the 'sidebar' will appear underneath the main content rather than actually being to the side when a narrow viewport is detected.  At this point, these divs will float in pairs horizontally rather than stack on top of each other, i.e.

```
.sidebaritem {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

No problem with that - but if there are an ODD number of divs, I'd like the LAST div to have a width of 100% so that it fills the available space, as opposed to the width:50% - which leaves a blank space where it's not needed (should there not be another div available to float beside it.)

Hopefully the image here better explains:

[image]

Is it possible ONLY with CSS to apply the 100% width on the last div (if there's an odd number of them,) assuming all the divs have the same class and we don't know ahead of time how many there are?  (I said 3 or 4 to cover the odd/even options, but it might be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc.)

I understand this can be done with JS, but despite not being able to figure it out it seems like it might be 'doable' using some combination of CSS3 selectors, which is what I'm looking for if at all possible.  An adjacent selector declaration seemed like it might do the trick, but again, they all have the same class - so .sidebaritem + .sidebaritem seems to always ring true whether it's odd or even.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML of this section of your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sidebaritem:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd){
    width:100%;
}
```

You can try something like this.
This select the last element only if is odd.

Comment: Why not just `.sidebaritem:last-child:nth-child(odd)`?

Comment: Well thank you kindly cesare for the quick answer, and as well to you Itay for the shorter code - I didn't know either was an option but they both worked great!